# Microsoft ClickOnce update fails with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, clickonce

Help

I have a Click Once solution and within the last few updates of our software, **ClickOnce** it fails at the end of the update with the error "**device can not be installed**".  When you go back to run the software, it says it can not be started etc and it has "**Value does not fall within the expected range.**" within the main logs.  This seems to be an issue around Windows 7 PCs.  This does not seem to be all Windows 7 and we have not seen it on Windows 10.  This only seems to happen with our clients and every test in-house, we do not have this issue.

The error we get is below, has anyone else had this issue and found a fix can you please share.

Comment: Please update with the error and log you refer to (you must have forgotten to add them?)

Comment: Hi Stein Asmul, the thing with the first error it is very hard to capture as its done before we see the issue.  But I have asked the support\software release team to try and get the logs for both on the next release push tomorrow.